# Unity Multiplayer:Camera Only following one player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I built a game using Survival Shooter asset of unity.The problem i face is that the camera only follows the host player in the host device while none of the players are followed in the other client devices.

**Camera Follow**

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{

    Transform target;            // The position that that camera will be following.
    public float smoothing = 5f;        // The speed with which the camera will be following.

    Vector3 offset;                     // The initial offset from the target.

    void Start ()
    {
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;
        offset = transform.position - target.position;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        // Create a postion the camera is aiming for based on the offset from the target.
        Vector3 targetCamPos = target.position + offset;

        // Smoothly interpolate between the camera's current position and it's target position.
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, targetCamPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

**LocalPlayerSetup Script**

```
public class LocalPlayerSetup : NetworkBehaviour 
{

  void Start()
  {
    GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("EnemyManager").SetActiveRecursively (true);

    if (isLocalPlayer) {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("MainCamera").GetComponent<CameraFollow> ().enabled = true;
        GetComponent<PlayerMovement> ().enabled = true;
        GetComponentInChildren<PlayerShooting> ().enabled = true;
   }

}
```

Comment: `FindGameObjectWithTag` may not behave well when there are multiple objects sharing that tag. I'd recommend that you find some other way of associating the camera and player objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not assign the target for the camera in its Start method. Instead make it public and assign it in the start method of the local player like this:

```
if (isLocalPlayer) {
    ("MainCamera").GetComponent<CameraFollow> ().target = transform;
}
```

Comment: gave an error **UnassignedReferenceException: The variable target of CameraFollow has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the target variable of the CameraFollow script in the inspector.**

Comment: I had accedently deleted the <CameraFollow> ().enabled = true; which was causing the error.Thank you for the help